# How to use source port to send and receive data by TCP/IP in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, tcp, asyncsocket

I have started a client in my system. It is running on port no 7913. I am sending a request data via TCP/IP from Java to server socket running on 7913.

> log is Message sent to Socket [addr=/190.161.153.109,port=7913,localport=54717]

I have also received the response from server for that particular data. Now the server is also trying to send a request to my localport 54717, not to port where my application is listening [ie 7913].

How to handle the request? When I try to connect with telnet to my localport, connection is refused.

The code:

```
public static String ickTransport(String ickHeader,String ickdata, Socket connection) throws UnknownHostException, IOException

    try
    {
        connection.setSoTimeout(Integer.parseInt(ickTimeOut));
        log.debug("ick Message for "+connection.toString()+" is " + ickMessage);            
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        DataOutputStream osw = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        osw.writeShort(Integer.parseInt(ickHeader));
        osw.writeBytes(ickMessage);
        osw.flush();

        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        int numberRecords   = stream.readShort();   
        if (numberRecords > 0) {
            int nSizeRead = 0;
            byte[] bRequest = new byte[numberRecords];

            int nSizeBuffer;
            for (; numberRecords > 0; numberRecords -= nSizeBuffer) {
              byte[] bBuffer = new byte[numberRecords];
              nSizeBuffer = stream.read(bBuffer);
              System.arraycopy(bBuffer, 0, bRequest, nSizeRead, nSizeBuffer);
              nSizeRead += nSizeBuffer;
            }
            ickResponse = new String(bRequest);
            log.debug("Response from ick is " + ickResponse);
        }               
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) 
    {
        log.error(e.getMessage());       
    }

    return ickResponse;
```

Comment: You have some misunderstanding how TCP/IP works.

Comment: You would have to listen on that additional port first.

Comment: My scenario is server wont sent the request to the socket server port. Instead it tries to send the request to last served port. In this case its 54717. But once the response is received, this port 54717 closes. How can i make it accept in my coding. kindly guide me.

Comment: The connection does not magically close. If it is closed, you do that in your program.

Comment: Client application receives the response from the server for the Request i have sent. But Now the server is also trying to send a new fresh request to my localport 54717, not to port where my application is listening [ie 7913]. am not closing my thread nor the socket. But the request doesn't comes to my application itself. how to keep the connection[localport 54717] alive to get fresh requests? any sample code, please guide me

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is going on you should understand what is **listen** socket and how it differs from connection **socket**.

When your application listens it (this `ServerSocket` does):

- Attaches to the port that you specify in `bind` request or in constructor
- Ask JVM to receive new connection on that port
- When connection is received listen socket changes it state and provide you new socket for new connection with `accept` method.

When your application establishes NEW connection it use `connect` method. Unless you use `bind` request on socket it:

- Allocates new dynamic port (54717 in your example)
- Sends connect request to the server
- After connection established you can use it for sending/receiving requests to/from server

Because nobody listens this dynamic port telnet requests are refused on it.

Comment: My scenario is server wont sent the request to the socket server port. Instead it tries to send the request to last served port. In this case its 54717. But once the response is received, this port 54717 closes. How can i make it accept in my coding. kindly guide me.

Comment: If you are writing client application you don't need listen socket at all. Just use connection that you establishes (from port 54717) to server for all request/responses. If it closed it is closed either by your application or because applications exits.

Comment: Client application receives the response from the server for the Request i have sent. But Now the server is also trying to send a new fresh request to my localport 54717, not to port where my application is listening [ie 7913]. am not closing my thread nor the socket. But the request doesn't comes to my application itself. how to keep the connection[localport 54717] alive to get fresh requests? any sample code please!